# How to use useMatch and useResolvedPath to validate non exactly match?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating an aplication with any routes and sub routes. This aplication has a SideBar with link to routes(pages) and this routes(pages) has links to subroutes(subpages). I want to set active class when the link match(non exactly), example:

links:

1. /users
2. /teams
3. /settings
   (/teams/name-of-team/squads) => /teams OK!
   (/users/teams/234) => /users OK!

Now, i'm using react router dom v6v example(https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/custom-link?file=src%2FApp.tsx) but this return true only when match exactly!

The routes:

```js
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="status" element={<Status />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route path="reset-password/:token" element={<ResetPassword />} />

        <Route path="/" element={<LoggedArea />}>

          {/* Inicio */}
          <Route index element={<Personal />} />

          {/* Dashboards */}
          <Route path="dashboards">
            <Route index element={<Dashboards />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Vagas */}
          <Route path="jobs">
            <Route index element={<Jobs />} />
            <Route path=":name" element={<Jobs />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Documentos */}   
          <Route path="documents">
            <Route index element={<Files />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Files />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Usuários */}
          <Route path="users">
            <Route index element={<Users />} />
            <Route path="create" element={<CreateUser />} />
            <Route path=":name" element={<User />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Times */}
          <Route path="teams">
            <Route index element={<Teams />} />
            <Route path=":name" element={<Team />}>
              <Route index element={<Heading3>Resumo</Heading3>} />
              <Route path="overview" element={<Heading3>Resumo</Heading3>} />
              <Route path="goals" element={<TeamGoals />} />
              <Route path="squads" element={<TeamSquads />} />
              <Route path="settings" element={<TeamSettings />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>

          {/* Componentes */}
          <Route path="ui">
            <Route index element={<Ui />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Configurações */}
          <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />}>
            <Route index element={<ProfileSettings />} />
            <Route path="profile" element={<ProfileSettings />} />
            <Route path="security" element={<SecuritySettings />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

My custom link component:

```js
interface SideMenuItemProps {
    icon    : React.ReactNode;
    label: string;
    url: string;
    tooltip?: boolean;
}

export function SideMenuItem(props: SideMenuItemProps) {

    const resolved = useResolvedPath(props.url)

    const match = useMatch({
        path: resolved.pathname,
        end: true
    })
    
    return(
        <li className={styles.item}>
            <Tooltip disabled={!props.tooltip} label={props.label} > 
                <Link to={props.url} className={`${styles.link} ${match ? styles.active : ''} `}>
                    {props.icon}
                </Link>
            </Tooltip>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link) component that handles this active matching for you? Have you [included all relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I don't see where any `SideBar` component is rendered within the router. Can you also try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?